# How to infer component props using InferProps?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to infer the props from the PropTypes of the component in order to prevent more boilerplate with the types. I did it this way:

```
type ButtonProps = InferProps<typeof Button.propTypes>;

const Button: FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = ({
  children,
  htmlType,
}: ButtonProps): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <button className="py-2 px-4 bg-black text-white" type={htmlType}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

Button.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  htmlType: PropTypes.oneOf<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>['type']>([
    'button',
    'submit',
    'reset',
  ]).isRequired,
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  htmlType: 'button',
};
```

But I have two errors:

- `TS2456: Type alias 'ButtonProps' circularly references itself.`
- `'Button' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.`

Any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You might have overcomplicated the type declaration of your component. You only need to type Button as `FC<Props>`, and you can strip away the return and parameter type declarations.

```
const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({
  children,
  htmlType,
}) => {
  return (
    <button className="py-2 px-4 bg-black text-white" type={htmlType}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Partially works amigo , but the Button.defaultProps are not taken into account, so when I call the component elsewhere it asks me to pass the data of the required props even though I have already declared them in the defaultProps object with the help of PropType.

Comment: Hmm.. you are saying that the `htmlType` prop is still required when you try to declare the component somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah amigo, it's so weird

Comment: I am thinking that you can try to use TypeScript's `omit` utility to omit `htmlType` from `ButtonProps`? I am not sure what is the best approach tbh. I don't have much experience with InferProps

Comment: It's all good amigo, I really appreciate your help. I implemented the solution that you gave me and it's better now, I have less boilerplate with types and all that stuff I had.